# What is the best way to detect that a recursive function is called by another function, not by function itself?

Tags: c, recursion

Suppose I have a recursive function `rec_fun()` and it have two block of code, `block_1` and `block_n`. `block_1` must execute only once when `rec_fun()` is initially called by another function like `main()` and `block_n` must execute every time `rec_fun()` is called, whether by another function or by function itself.

```
rec_fun()
{
   {
      ...
      //block_1
      //must be executed on first call only
      ...
   }

   {
      ...
      //block_n
      //with recursive call and exit condition
      ...
   }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? I have thought few ways like using a counter `i` as parameter to `rec_fun()` initially passed with 0 and incrementing it in subsequent call, so that the function can determine whether it is first call or not. Another approach is to put `block_n` in another helper function and call it from `rec_fun()`. But in first approach I have to pass an unnecessary argument `0` and second approach creates an unnecessary function. What is the best way to accomplish this, according to you?

I'll appreciate if you provide some useful links to learn recursion.

Comment: Does `block_1` have to be invoked on _every_ [outer] call to `rec_fun` from `main`? Or, does `block_1` need to be invoked _only_ once _regardless_ of whether `rec_fun` is called from `main` or itself?

Comment: @CraigEstey `block_1` have to be invoked only on every [outer] call to `rec_fun()` from `main()`.

Comment: Just make a wrapper function executing the first block, then the recursive portion. And no, it is not an "unnecessary function". It is necessary if you need this functionality.

Comment: It's very common to have a recursive "helper" function that's used from the user-visible function.

Comment: You've outlined the two most common solutions. For the first solution, I typically call the extra parameter `depth`. Knowing the depth of the recursion is often useful for debugging, as well as for identifying the initial call. For the second solution, you can put the top level function and the helper in a separate file. Declare the helper as `static` so that it's not visible outside that file.

Comment: In languages that allow nested functions, the recursive function would often be defined inside the non-recursive function, so it can't be called directly.

Answer (score 3):

Hide it behind a layer of indirection:

```
func()
{
   //block_1
   // compute what you need  
   // and pass it to rec_fun either as value, or as a pointer

   rec_func(&block_1_result);
}
```

And make sure you expose only `func` for your users.

> and second approach creates an unnecessary function

So? Unless you are in an extremely limited environment like an embedded device with very limited memory that's really not an issue. And the function is not "unnecessary". It's unnecessary if you think the user doesn't need 2 functions, but it's necessary if you think from the implementation view: it's needed by the implementation (actually it's one solution, but still the argument holds).

Comment: This can actually *help* in extremely limited environments. Low-end systems often have quite a bit of ROM (to store code) but much more limited space for RAM (to store volatile data). In such a case, using a bit of extra ROM to save RAM (by not passing an extra parameter in every recursive call) is usually the right trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

I will go against your intuition completely and will suggest to *combine* the two approaches you consider inappropriate. Because they are appropriate. I will create a recursive implementation with extra parameter, but for convenience and "hiding" I will also make a wrapper function:

```
void rec_func(bool init) 
{
    if (init) {
        /* initialization logoc */
    }
    /* common recursive code */
    rec_func(false);

}

void wrapper_func(void)
{
    rec_func(true);
}
```

Note, nothing is "unnecessary" here. The extra parameter helps to keep the function logic in one unit. The wrapper function helps the caller not to mess with unrelated parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The C language does not give the function any information regarding its caller so there is no portable way to test whether `rec_fun()` was called from another function or recursively from itself.

Your goal can be achieved by passing an extra argument to the function with a different value for outsider and recursive calls. This is cumbersome and error prone.

The standard approach for your problem is to use an ancillary function `rec_fun1()`: the main function `rec_fun()` is called from other functions and the recursive ancillary function is called from `rec_fun()` and recursively from `rec_fun1()` itself.

A classic example of this is `mergesort()` which would allocate the temporary work array and call a recursive `mergesort1()` that uses the temporary array to perform the top down merge sort algorithm. Upon return from the call to `mergesort1()`, `mergesort()` frees the temporary array and returns to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution is usually the correct one.

The second function isn't any less necessary than any other function. You have one function that defines what is needed to implement whatever it is that the external caller expects your code to do. You have another to define whatever it is that you're going to do recursively.

Those apparently do different things and meet different requirements. As such, it's *entirely* appropriate that they be implemented in different functions.

It's possible to combine these into a single function that varies its behavior depending on a parameter that's passed. If the difference in behavior is small enough, this can be a somewhat reasonable approach--but I would say having one function do two different sorts of things is generally a kludge. The only question is whether it's a small enough kludge that you choose to overlook its being kludgy, or a big enough one that you shouldn't overlook it.

As so ensuring that the second function isn't accidentally called by some "outsider", the usual is to make it a static function, so you'd have a structure on this general order:

foo.h

```
#pragma once
int foo(int);
```

foo.c

```
typedef result_t /* whatever */;

static result_t blocka(int) {
    // stuff for block a
}

static int blockb(result_t const *) {
    // stuff for block b
}

int foo(int input) {
   result_t internal_result = blocka(input);
   return blockb(&internal_result);
}
```

In this case, I've written both `blocka` and `blockb` as separate "unnecessary" functions. Since I don't know what either your block a or block b does, it's hard to guess whether that's justified or not. But I would not start by thinking in terms of whether a function is *necessary*. Rather the opposite, for almost any block of code with a reasonably well defined interface and functionality, writing a function to embody that block of code should be more or less the default.

For example, if you have an `if`/`then`/`else` kind of situation:

```
if (foo) {
    // do foo stuff
} else {
    // do not-foo stuff
}
```

Think about/ask yourself whether you can give a meaningful name to the "do foo stuff" block and/or the "do not-foo stuff" blocks. That is, can you give a name to what they're doing?

If so, there's a reasonable chance that they should be implemented as functions, and then your `if`/`then`/`else` block can become a more readable, higher-level guide to what's going on:

```
if (data_sorted(input))
    process_sorted_data(input);
else
    process_random_data(input);
```

Moving these blocks of code into (reasonably well-named) functions makes it much easier for a reader to understand the *intent* behind the code, rather than having to divine your intent from the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static variable as counter.

```
rec_fun()
{
   static int i = 0;

   if (++i == 1) {
      ...
      //block_1
      //must be executed on first call only
      ...
   }

   {
      ...
      //block_n
      //with recursive call and exit condition
      ...
   }

   --i; // internal house keeping to track whether internal, or external caller 
}
```

Comment: This will only work the first time the function is called.

Comment: @Barmar Do you see --i; before exiting funciton? How you say this iwll work only the first time called?

Comment: I didn't notice that. If you edit the question to make it clearer I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @chqrlie if you read question carryfully you will see that  the OP's goal is exactly block_1 should be called every time the function is called from a different caller.

Comment: I didn't notice it before, I saw it after your comment. But I can't change my vote if the answer isn't edited.

Comment: @Barmar - OP edited, but I noticed did not notify you after.

Comment: After editing per someone's request, its good to tag them in a comment. :)

Comment: What did you change? I think just whitespace. You should add an explanation of how `--i` is used as part of the solution.

Comment: Maybe something like `--i;//internal house keeping to track whether internal, or external caller`  You cannot expect your concept to be as intuitive to all as it may be to you.  If I got it wrong, then correct it in your answer.   And if I can offer a soft suggestion - go light when telling people how they should vote.   :)

Comment: @ryyker i dont care votes. i just mention it because i got two false comments from two people who has thousands answers here.

Comment: Since you do not care about votes, then it must be the pure exhilaration of helping others to understand a concept, or to layout a viable method to address OP questions (which is apparently what this answer is doing.)  If that is the case, then adding some words, in the form of sentences outside the code to describe what your code does, why it does what it does, or why it answers the question, or comments within the code to explain what a code segment is for.  There is still room for improvement to make this a great answer instead of _just_ an answer.  (Its worth at least +1 to me.)

Comment: @ryyker You are right. thank you for your comments. i just dont want to think how many false comments these guys made with their thousands answers.

Comment: _"i just dont want to think how many false comments these guys made..._.  Not too many - Ive seen their answers, and their comments in many places.  Their intent is always to be helpful, and they usually hit that mark.

Comment: Your approach is interesting but it has shortcomings: adding a global static state makes the function non reentrant: you should at least make the `i` variable thread based and you still cannot handle the case where the code in `block_n` calls another function which indirectly calls `rec_fun()` again. In this pathological example, `block_1` should be executed for this indirect recursion but it wont with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter that you change as you move down the recursion and make block 1 ran based on the condition of the parameter. If you use an if/else if for block 1 and 2 then you're good.

```
your_func(the_param){
    if(the_param) {
        // the code that only runs on the first call
        }
    else if(the_param) {
        // the code that runs every other call
        }
```